# content ::before over two divs with overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to do this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XViGZ.png)

My problem is that I need to hide the getting out of bounds on the X-axis and that would be content ::before was on top of the two div's.

As I understand it is a common element in design and I would like to know how to do it better.

```css
section.another {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #51D145;
}

section.out-mission {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

}
section.out-mission::before {
  content: url("https://fakeimg.pl/200x200/");
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}
  
p.text {
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="another">
    
  </section>
  <section class="out-mission">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    our mission
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="text">
                    НПФ «НОРД» – разработчик уникального направления, на основе регулируемых газовых сред (РГС), в
                    области производства экологически-чистого продукта.
                </p>
                <p class="text">
                    Технология РГС позволяет производить в промышленных масштабах, свободные от болезней и патогенов,
                    качественные и полезные продукты (на этапах выращивания, переработки и хранения):
                </p>
                <p class="text">мясо и птицу без использования антибиотиков и гормонов; овощи и зеленые культуры без
                    применения пестицидов и агрохимикатов.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have added one div over both sections and given `overflow-x: hidden` to that `div`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/bLhu0qcm/

Comment: yeah it's work right, but maybe you can explain why it's doesn't work if i set `overflow-x: hidden` for body tag?

Comment: we can apply overflow-x: hidden to the body, but then if in any section we are getting scrollbar, we can not identify where the issue has occurred. Therefore it is good to not give overflow-x: hidden; in the body tag.